# update datetime field in same table sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this table structure of sql server 2008. I want to update mom_reportedon with createdon datetime field. I tried this below sql statements but it's failed. How can I try this?

```
Update table1
set reportedon = createdon
where name is not null

update table1
set reportedon = convert(datetime,'2012-03-29 17:50:59.000')
where mom_name is not null
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of doing this would be something like:

```
UPDATE T1 SET reportedon = T2.createdon
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table1 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

Where 'id' is the primary key. However, this looks like it might be 'name' in the example above, which would mean:

```
UPDATE T1 SET reportedon = T2.createdon
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table1 T2 ON T1.name = T2.name
```

(And yes, you would be INNER JOINing your table with itself, there)

Comment: hi Scott, when i try your sql statment, i got this error message "The table 'table1' is ambiguous.". thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE T1 SET reportedon = T2.createdon
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table1 T2 ON T1.name = T2.name
where T1.name is not null
```

Comment: Hi AnandPhadke, when i try your sql query,unfortunately it's failed. The error message is "Update or insert of view or function 'T1' failed because it contains a derived or constant field."